# Blender 2.8 How to rotate viewport 90 deg after Shift +7

Tags: 3d-view

It is in Blender 2.8
Hello , I want to work perpendicular to the surface in orthogonal view. After I press Shift +7 I get that view BUT I want to be able to rotate that view in 90 degrees increments. How do I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the navigation options under View > Navigation and their corresponding hotkeys to pan, orbit and rotate the view in 15 degree increments.

[image]

If I understand your description correctly, what you are looking for is numpad 4 and 6 to orbit.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! Works great.